# How to play a MMS channel in Android?

Tags: android, windows-media-services, microsoft-media-server

My code, But it not working:

```
String LINK = "mms://202.71.98.44/cmtv";
        VideoView video_view_ = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager
            .LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        video_view_.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(LINK));
        video_view_.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        video_view_.requestFocus();
        video_view_.start();
```

How play a channel in android?